# Broken ActiveX in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I hope this is the correct forum to post this, I believe this to be an Excel issue.

Ever since I upgraded to Win 7 (64 bit), whenever I try to add an ActiveX control to a worksheet in Excel 2003, I just get the "Cannot insert object" message. This seemed to be related to the “Microsoft 12/9/2014 Update Breaks ActiveX Controls” issue I see discussed in the various forums. However, none of the fixes worked for me, and none appear to address Excel 2003. Excel 2010 works just fine.

So here’s what I’ve tried so far:

1 - Removed all updates that I was able to.

2 - Uninstalled Excel 2003, Excel 2010, Windows Live Mail, and Microsoft Money Plus.

3 - Deleted all *.exd files.

4 - Did a clean install of Excel 2003.

This didn’t fix the problem, and I’m out of ideas – so I’m hoping someone has some suggestions.

Comment: Just noticed this - if I try to do an `Excel.exe /regserver` I always get the message `One of your object libraries (stdile32.tlb) is missing or damaged.  Please run Setup to install it`.  Which I have done, but I still keep getting that message.  I'm thinking this may be related to my original question.

Comment: I also tried [this fix](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-office_install/stdole32tlb-file-missing/ba3e940d-d628-4334-ac89-5e8ac9878093) suggested by Sachin Shetty, but no joy.

Comment: I finally came up with a solution to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108355/excel-2003-active-x-bug-from-dec-2014-update-still-broke-what-else-to-try/33383587#33383587)

Answer (score 1):

I found that "Forms" provides the same controls.  A bit more cumbersome but it works!

Go to View - "Toolbars" - "Forms" and turn on the toolbar.  Then select the object from the ribbon.

Gordon

Comment: I, too, have switched to Forms controls instead of ActiveX. I kept running into little oddities. The most annoying one was when buttons would move around the page whenever it was saved. That file was fubar. Forms are limited in several ways compared to ActiveX but I have found them to be much more robust and I prefer robustness over aesthetics.